# svn2git is ignoring "--username"-parameter

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I just tried importing an svn-repo to a git repo, but I'm facing a bit of a problem. After starting to import the first repo with `svn2git http://path.to.repo.com/repos/a/ --username abc --verbose` i thought "this is taking too long". And since at this time it's only for testing purposes, I decided to `CTRL-C` and import a smaller repository first. So I typed in `svn2g http://path.to.repoe.com/repos/b/ --username xyz --verbose`.

That gave me this

```
URL access forbidden for unknown reason: access to 'http://svn.path.to.repo.com/repos/b/' forbidden at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/Git/SVN.pm line 303
```

I'm sure, the username is the correct one, so I took a look at the svn_access_log and there I saw, that everytime I run the second command with `--username xyz` this pops up in my svn_access_log:

```
{arbitrary IP} - - [31/Oct/2013:08:48:15 +0100] "OPTIONS /repos/b HTTP/1.1" 401 401
{arbitrary IP} - abc [31/Oct/2013:08:48:15 +0100] "OPTIONS /repos/b HTTP/1.1" 403 211
```

How come, svn2git uses the wrong username here, even though I provide it?

UPDATE: 
It worked, after I ran `svn co http://path.to.repo.com/repos/b/ --username xyz`. Can anyone explain that to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this works:

```
svn co http://path.to.repo.com/repos/b/ --username xyz.
svn2git http://path.to.repo.com/repos/a/ --username abc --verbose
```

That should means the `svn co` has cached the credentials on the svn side, and the `svn2git` command has reused that successfully.

Comment: `svn2git --help` states, that the order is first URL and then options, that's why I didn't try that. Somehow it seems to work now for me...Weird.

Comment: @Vince did you try to passe the username in the url directly? `svn2git http://abc@path.to.repo.com/repos/a/`

Comment: No, I did not. As it's working now, I can't get it back to a state, where it doesn't work, so I can't test if that makes a difference...

Comment: @Vince maybe your `svn co` did cache the credentials on the svn side: I have rewritten the answer to reflect that.